# How to save expression with its name

Tags: output-formatting, output, save

I want to save expressions as well as their names in a file.

```
  func[i_] := i;
  Do[func[i] >>> out.m,{i,1,3}];
```

The output is

```
   cat out.m

   1
   2
   3
```

However the desired output is

```
   cat out.m

   func[1] = 1;
   func[2] = 2;
   func[3] = 3;
```

`Save` does not save here.

Comment: What about `DumpSave`?

Comment: I do not know, but with that also I am unable to produce the expected output.

Comment: What do you want to export, the function names alone, or the definitions? The syntax you have there would result in the `out.m` being overwritten each time. I think you’re looking for something like [`OpenWrite`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/OpenWrite.html) see [here](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/guide/BasicInputAndOutputInPrograms.html) for some other examples.

Comment: With  [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/DumpSave.html) you should be able to use the third option down in the templated examples, for this question.

Comment: The overwriting is a different thing. My issue here is to write the function name as well as its definition/expression. `Save` would have worked if I just define just say `fun1=func[1]`, then it would have written inside out.m as `fun1=1`. But I want `func[1]=1` in the output. And in a generic case this `func` definition may not be this simple.

Comment: More explicitly `Save["out.m",func[1]]` will fail.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Save`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html) in this way:

```
func[i_] := func[i] = i;
Do[func[i], {i, 1, 3}];
FullDefinition@func
(*
func[1] = 1

func[2] = 2

func[3] = 3

func[i_] := func[i] = i
*)

Save["out.m",func];
ClearAll[func]; Get["out.m"]; FullDefinition@func
(*
func[1] = 1

func[2] = 2

func[3] = 3

func[i_] := func[i] = i
*)
```

So, here, we show that memoization can be used as a method to record the defined expressions when one is going to save them externally.

Your suggested method of using `Save` was not exactly proper, which is why it would not work for you. Here, this plays out as expected. While the memoized func name cannot be avoided in this procedure, it seems to do as you would like.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
func[i_] := i

Do[ 
    "func["<>ToString@i<>"] = "<>ToString@func@i >>> "out.m"
   , {i,1,3}
  ]
```

**Edit 1**: It's not clear to me what's your scope but, this does what you asked

```
"func["<>ToString@#<>"] = "<>ToString@func@# & /@ Range@3 // 
Export["out.m", #~StringRiffle~"\n"<>"\n","Text"]&
```

**Edit 2**: Given that your scope is to create a file that contains only the `DownValues` of a symbol `f`, you do not need to define a substitution rule (`:=`) for `f`. So, let's just define the `DownValues` of f and export them in a text file

```
Remove@f    

f@#~Set~# &/@ Range@3

ToString@Information[f]@"DownValues" // 
Export["out.m",#,"Text"]&
```

Comment: It produces `"func[1]=1"`. Without running shell commands is it possible to remove `"` ?

Comment: @Boogeyman see Edit 1

Comment: The scope is very clear if you want to create an output which you can directly translate from Mathematica to other languages eg. symbolic manipulation system like `Form`. :)

Comment: Why you define `func`in advance? you could have just defined another function `g[i_]:=1` and then append `f[i] = g[i]`. If you see @Fraccalo answer, it has all those `Hold`-related function solely because you had defined `func` in advance

Comment: Yes I can do that. But this is the whole point. You have to define just another function in order to save it in a nice form. My question is very simple. You had a function definition and you want to print it with its expression as well as its names. Now if you do define , its just extra definition which to me is not justified just for printing. This is why I wanted to ask if there is nicer way to handle.

Comment: @Boogeyman, see Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ToString[#] <> "=" <> ToString[ReleaseHold@#] <> ";" &@
    HoldForm@func[#] & /@ Range[3]

(# >>> out.m) & /@ list
```